# Opentext case360 What does Process Instance WFState -200 mean

Tags: workflow, opentext

I'm using the opentext case360 product

I looked in a process table and noticed that a number of process instances have the WFState -200 I looked in the help documentation and -200 is not there.

Does anybody know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WFState 200 means waiting for client/user to process the instance and route it on.

Answer (score 1):

If you look into the help, you'll see a table for the WFState values.  -200 is probably exiting activity error.

Answer (score 1):

WFStat -200 means that there are some issues while the item was waiting to be processed by user. It means "client access error". You can update it to 200 and try to lock the item. Usually this works but in case again it changes to -200 you need to check the logs from Toolbox.

Note: all WFstates lower than 0 are error states which related to the same but positive state: -200 error > 200 , -100 error > 100